# What does the word "monetise" mean here?

Tags: meaning

What does the word "monetise" mean here?

NexTable will give Zomato another service to complement its listings, and potentially better monetise them.

Comment: You could say -
'the new service will allow the existing listings to start generating more money/income'

Comment: Hello, @T Cat. If you're as new as I think here, and you used a 'comment' rather than an 'answer' to answer a question that obviously is sadly lacking in reasonable research, well done! I'll be on the lookout to upvote answers of yours (where appropriate, of course).

Comment: Must be related to pornography. I'm not touching it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Monetize/monetise** means to generate money. In e-commerce and retail, it means to generate revenue.

Answer (score 0):

When a new business, especially of the "e-business" variety (eg, Twitter), is formed, it is sometimes the case that founders do not know exactly how it will make money.  (I still don't understand how Twitter makes money.)  So the business will be formed and get running, and only then do the owners attempt to implement a mechanism for actually making money (through advertising, etc).  This step in the business start-up process is known as "monetizing".

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer is insufficiently specific. Monetizing indeed implies making money, but it specifically means the process of turning non-revenue generating assets (in the example: listings) into revenue-generating assets.